Which USB3.1 superspeed pairs (SSTX1* / SSRX1* or SSTX2 / SSTX) are active when e.g. CC1 is driven?
Consider when a USB cable connects a host/source (downstream facing port, DFP) to a peripheral/sink (upstream facing port, UFP) and only half of the superspeed pairs are used, the cable will connect one CC* line and ground the other, like so:

Which superspeed pairs will be active / connected?
image source

SSTX1* and SSRX1* pairs are active / connected when CC1 is driven.
Likewise,
SSTX2* and SSRX2* pairs are active / connected when CC2 is driven.
